# SQL Join and Manipulate

Tags: sql, select, left-join

I have TABLE1 and TABLE2 as below:

##### TABLE1

| STUDENT | DAY | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 9 | 10 |

##### TABLE2

| STUDENT | DAY | TEST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 2 |
| 1 | 9 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 | 9 |
| 4 | 4 | 10 |

I need a query to JOIN TABLE2 to TABLE1 and then create column `SCOREVSTEST` which goes like this:

```
if SCORE >= TEST then SCOREVSTEST = 'SCORE >= TEST'
if SCORE < TEST then SCOREVSTEST = 'SCORE < TEST'
```

This my desirable output

| STUDENT | DAY | SCORE | TEST | SCOREVSTEST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 0 | 1 | SCORE < TEST |
| 1 | 9 | 10 | 7 | SCORE >= TEST |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 5 | SCORE < TEST |

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
    ON TABLE1.STUDENT = TABLE2.STUDENT
    AND TABLE1.DAY = TABLE2.DAY
CASE WHEN SCORE >= TEST THEN 'SCORE>= TEST'
ELSE 'SCORE<TEST' END AS SCOREVSTEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but this `case` expression should be in the `select` list, not part of or after the `join`:

```sql
SELECT    table1.student, table1.day, score, test,
          CASE WHEN score >= test THEN 'SCORE >= TEST' ELSE 'SCORE < TEST' END 
            AS scorevtest
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON ON table1.student = table2.student AND table1.day = table2.day
```

Comment: it is is possible to say

SELECT *, CASE WHEN... ?

Comment: @bvowe It depends on the database. Some allow this, others do not. But generally `SELECT *` is considered poor practice anyway, and `*` is often only used while still building the query. It will be replaced with the actual column list before using a query in production.

Comment: @bvowe yes, it is.